Not being able to query select an element that should exist
I have a very bizarre issue with a vanilla JS script placed on a SPA (react) website. I have this event listener, that should theoretically wait for the website to fully load before executing:
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        try {
            initialiseTracking();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

Here comes the bizarre part:
const initialiseTracking = () => {
    console.log('initialiseTracking()');
    console.log('document.readyState: ', document.readyState);
    console.log('document.body: ', document.body); // always logs correctly with element existing within
    const croElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-ab="test-item"]');
    console.log('croElements: ', croElements, croElements.length);
};

For some reason, the croElements is sometimes empty, and sometimes not, despite the document.body always logging the body structure with the element with the data-ab="test-item" attribute.
The log contains the element: <button data-ab="test-item">Download</button> - and no, it isn’t dynamically rendered; it always should.
I couldn’t create a demo for this unfortunately and it’s too difficult to show the full environment (it’s basically a react page with the above code in a script tag in the head) so I know there’s limited information to go on, but does anyone have a hunch about why the croElements only sometimes finds the element despite it always logging to be present? Or any ideas of what I could try? (Note: I don’t want a mutation observer because on some pages that use the script a croElement may not exist).
Thanks…

"despite the document.body always logging the body structure with the element" - that doesn't mean much. Try logging document.body.outerHTML instead

"it isn’t dynamically rendered" - are you saying it's part of the HTML coming from the server, or is it rendered (or replaced) by the SPA, and you mean it just isn't rendered conditionally?

"load event listener, that should theoretically wait for the website to fully load before executing" - it will wait for some resources to load, but it does not mean it will wait for the React SPA to have finished rendering

Good spot - logging document.body.outerHTML actually returns this when it doesn't work: <body class=""><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root" style="overflow-x:hidden"></div></body> - and when it sometimes does work, this logs the correct body with the element visible

By dynamically rendered, I meant it isn't conditionally rendered. Not sure of the technical specifics of how it works, presumably rendered by the SPA, but I know it's not conditionally rendered

if load is not the right way forward, is there another way of detecting when the react SPA has made its initial render?

You could poll (run a delay loop) until you find the element, or use the mutation observer you've mentioned, but of course the proper solution would be to modify the code of the React component that renders the button. Can you do that?

Also, depending on the application, you could also wait until the react root render() has been called for the first time, if you can locate (and modify) that code.

The issue with polling is that the element is only on some pages, and other pages without it use the same script so it may not exist always (hence why I don't think the mutation observer is right since I'd want it to stop after the page has loaded). I don't have access to the react code and the script is also placed on sites that may not be a SPA.

You can start the polling/mutation-observing only onload, and stop it after some timeout  (or as soon as the element is found) to optimise performance. But really without access to the SPA source code, you'll have a hard time coming up with an optimal solution.

If react has already loaded, would adding the load event listener still execute? Adding a check whether document.readyState is complete first seems like it might have fixed it, but I'm not sure on the reliability of this
